# How to insert search bar for material-ui MenuItem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can I insert a search input inside the  component?
I checked the [material-ui documentation.](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#menus), test couple thing around, still don't have luck.

here's the [demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/devextreme-react-grid-for-material-ui-udvyt?fontsize=14)

I tried:

```
const searchBar = `${<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />}`;
 <Menu
   keepMounted
   anchorEl={anchorEl}
   open={!!anchorEl}
   onClose={closeMenu}
>
  {filterValues.map(searchBar, value => (
   <MenuItem
   value={value || null}
   onClick={getChangeFilter(value)}
   selected={filterValue === value}
   key={Math.random()}
>
  {value}
  {searchBar}
   </MenuItem>
))}

      </Menu>
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using DevExtreme, I would think the [search](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/searching/#react-grid---searching) feature there would be useful.

It also has [filtering](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/filtering/), which I would suggest is probably a better user experience than how you're currently doing this. When I was playing around with your demo code, I got confused because I couldn't tell what values I was filtering on after clicking on them. Also, the "clearing" functionality might be a bit counter-intuitive as well.

Otherwise, here's a link to a [MaterialTableDemo](https://codesandbox.io/s/e0rtg) from the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have used the default filter function from DevExtreme, but the team is not happy with the layout, so trying to find the way to make it work. I not quite sure I can pass the search function from DevExtreme to the material-UI component. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi! Hope you've found a solution, but if not, have you taken a look at the example at https://codesandbox.io/s/e0rtg?

Comment: Thank you so much pitchdiesel , this is perfect! would you mind leave the answer below, so I can choose your, please! Thanks again!

Comment: Added it to the original answer!